# How to make a plotting library similar to MATLAB's in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, plot

For Education Purposes

Background
I am creating a small program just to learn more about C++ and numerical methods. I have the basic functionality , but a great draw back is that I can only output values through the console window. Further more I would like to make plots of function to know how they behave.

Question

How do I do this ? It will be easier/practical to go with a library like SDL , but like I said this is for "enlightenment" and I would like to learn how to do it directly without replying on a library.I guess I will have to call functions in windows to do this , am I right ?

I researched a bit , and learned about QT and using it to build applications. But I am not looking to build a large scale app , what I want to do is to simply replicate what matlab does , when I call plot , it opens a small window and shows me the plot, how do I get this done in C++ ?

-Thank you

Comment: You might want to pipe your data to a `gnuplot` process.  It accepts commands to control the plot.  BTW while there's some advantage to reducing dependencies, SDL is still going to give you complete control over rendering, not do it all for you.

Comment: And if you think that there is some plotting function in Windows you can simply call, you're going to be disappointed.  Windows provides drawing functions, to let you create a window, place text here, lines there.  Turning that into graphical representation of data is a lot of work.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes that is what I am looking for. I want to know how it works rather than get the hard part done for me. I will search online for Windows Drawing function. Do you have any tutorial or book you would recommend to learn about it ?

Comment: A very simple solution is to create a simple image file instead (*.BMP for instance) and then call the OS picture viewer. On Windows that's as simple as `system("start My.BMP");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a simple graph appear in a window using the pure Win32 API, then Raymond Chen's scratch program is a great place to start:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx

It provides all the window setup code, without hiding a single thing from you, ready for you to write the `PaintContent` function.

The `PaintContent` function accepts one parameter, the `PAINTSTRUCT` structure, and by far the most important field is the `hdc` -- handle to device context.

A device context is key to doing anything graphical.  You probably want to start by setting up coordinates so that you can draw in graph units instead of pixels.  For that, these functions are essential:

- `GetClientRect`, `SetMapMode`, `SetWindowExtEx`, `SetViewportExtEx`

Once you've set up the coordinate system, you can draw lines.  First up will be your plot box, you can use `FrameRect`.

After that, `Polyline` will draw an entire lineseries from an array of data.

Once you get that far, think about axis ticks (`MoveTo` and `LineTo`) and labels (`ExtTextOut`).

It really isn't *too* hard to get something recognizable as a graph.  Interaction with the user, such as pan, zoom, and data cursors are where the pain comes in.

The MSDN examples in ["Using Lines and Curves"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be very helpful for making plots.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you targeting?

I highly recommend using some kind of graphics framework that handles the platform specific issues for you.  Even the Windows platforms may have different screen sizes, resolutions and graphics handling.  This is why you use *drivers* and generic API.

If you want to go *raw* and develop everything yourself, you will need to study up on the field of Computer Graphics.  Linear Algebra would help too.

Unfortunately, the scope of your answer is too broad and large to fit on a StackOverflow answer.
(Universities offer classes in Graphics and that only scratches the surface of what you are looking for.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Most of my program is methods on Linear Algebra, so I am good in that part. Would you point to any websites / books that has the relevant information ? thank you.

Comment: I think you are confusing different layers of abstraction.  OSes (at least Windows, Linux, Mac) do have graphics drivers providing a hardware abstraction layer and consistent graphics handling, yet the screen sizes, resolutions, and dot pitch are different.  Computer graphics and linear algebra would be almost useless for direct hardware access, those operate at a much higher level of abstraction.  For example, *very* useful with OpenGL and/or Direct3D, which are the generic APIs that drivers provide.